# Add mermaid diagram in FastAPI docs description

Tags: python, fastapi, mermaid

I would like to add mermaid diagrams in the documentation description of FastAPI :

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
description = """
    <div class="mermaid">
            graph TD 
            A[Client] --> B[Load Balancer] 
            B --> C[Server01] 
            B --> D[Server02]
        </div>
    <script>
            mermaid.initialize({ startOnLoad: true });
        </script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mermaid/dist/mermaid.min.js"></script>
    """
app = FastAPI(description=description)
```

But it seems that fastapi erases the scripts tags and the "mermaid" class. How can i easily add mermaid diagrams ? I don't want to use an image.

Thank you

Comment: Did you try using Mermaid to create the diagram separately, and then using the resulting plain HTML for the FastAPI description?

Comment: Have you seen https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/extending-openapi/ for how to add custom functionality the the OpenAPI specification and how it's used in FastAPI?

Answer (score 0):

HTML tags are sanitized by the swagger markdown engine for security purposes. Unfortunately I think it's likely that this capability is disallowed by design.